# How does database engine handle concurrent inserts?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I tried to google up this question but found no question similar to this so I am asking here. This may seem like a noob question but I really don't know how does database handle concurrent inserts.

Say if 100 users fire up insert query. Does the database insert multiple records at the same time (same second, same nanosecond etc) or it inserts each record one after the other? Database runs in a multithreaded environment so the natural answer would be inserts fire up at the same time.

Comment: [Isolation Levels in the Database Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189122%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A database engine like SQL Server (which I assume you are asking about, since you tag it so) will use some version of the [ARIES](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~brewer/cs262/Aries.pdf) [Write-Ahead Logging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-ahead_logging) protocol. Since such a protocol requires the writing of the log as a sequential stream, it follows as a rule that 100 inserts fired concurrently, even on a 100 CPU server will have to serialize internally when they access the log. Therefore concurrency at the 'nanosecond' level, as you suggest, is not even theoretically possible. The topic is described on several places, see [Write-Ahead Transaction Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186259.aspx), [Transaction Recovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224747%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and [How It Works: Bob Dorr's SQL Server I/O Presentation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/03/24/how-it-works-bob-dorr-s-sql-server-i-o-presentation.aspx).

However, from a practical point of view, you should think in terms of transactions and [isolation levels](http://www.littlekendra.com/2011/02/08/isoposter/).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that users do inserts in their own transactions, the engine commits each transaction in isolation. As the commits make their way into the table, they get ordered in an arbitrary way, based on which thread gets what execution time slice earlier. If users insert data that interferes with table constraints (say, they insert non-unique values into a unique column) the transaction of one random user would succeed, while all the others would fail.