# Transaction read uncommited in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Consider situation when one user doing his transaction, then meantime other users from my understanding are not able to delete/update specific table - but what about read, are they able to read, and if so what will be data they would see? And what if they going to delete/update some records are going to get timeout due to transaction is ongoing? Any easy to understand example appreciated.

Comment: Depends on the database and the transaction isolation settings you use

Comment: Reads to a table typically occur in an Shared Lock (in case of pessimistic concurrency context). How locks work in [SQL Server](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-locking-in-sql-server).

Comment: Other users won't be able to delete or update any of those particular rows that the first user is working on - but updating a table does ***NOT*** lock the whole table! (only those rows involved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is ***WITH (NOLOCK)***.

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WITH (NOLOCK)
```

It will allow you to read uncommited rows of data.

For more info refer [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2470/understanding-the-sql-server-nolock-hint/).

Regarding the simultaneous changes in the table:
Simultaneous insert/updates etc. are theoretically impossible since SQL Server serializes it inside (like a log) having nanoseconds as an interval, thus making it impossible to create a simultaneos modify at the same time.

Comment: just would like to know what will be behaviour for this particurall isolation level (default one). As long they cannot update/delete are they able to read?

Comment: @JimmyJimm Which DBMS?

Comment: @Alex B. sql server

Comment: If I understand your question right, yes they can read the data. The data they will see will include the data being processed by the other transaction plus the existing records in the table. For example the other transaction is adding 100 records and you selected the table in the middle of the adding of _nth_ record, the result will include up to the _nth_ record only.

Comment: `While a shared lock is being held other transactions can read but can't modify locked data.`

Comment: @AlexB. just said it. As simple as that.

Comment: so simply saying read uncommited isolation behaviour other users are able to read ucommited data during other transaction is ongoing - they will see old and new data which is still not commited right?

Comment: @Crush Sundae ok understood. What if other users going to update/delete are they going to get timeout exception or?

Comment: Btw...you can just simulate that behavior. Create a test table and open several scopes (e.g. open multiple SSMS windows). Now open some explicit transactions and do some CRUD actions. Without commiting do a SELECT in another window. See what happens.

Comment: Regarding that, I think the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889478/how-does-database-engine-handle-concurrent-inserts

Comment: @Crush Sundae Have no access yet i will test. Perhaps other users selects will read old and new data (still not commited) - that's clear to me.Just would like to know this one more thing: What if other users going to update/delete are they going to get timeout exception or?

Comment: Check the link I inserted in my previous comment. It states there that the simultaneous insert/updates etc. are theoretically impossible since _SQL Server_ serializes it inside (like a log) having nanoseconds as an interval, thus making it impossible to create a _simultaneos_ modify at the same time.

Comment: If you create a dead lock, the DB will somehow resolve it (which process is killed can be customized). If you create a lock, the involved transactions will spin until hell freezes. However, it depends on how you access the DB. If you you use .NET Entity Framework e.g. there is a timeout for sql commands.

Comment: @Crush Sundae yes i read but still don;t get it - just simple question: if one user is doing update or insert - in meantime other user is going to initiate insert or update - what error message is going to be shown in sqlException? Would it be timeout or? (i use vb.net+net.framework)

Comment: So you mean they are both inserting or updating in the same table? There will be no timeouts or exceptions. Because (read my previous comment). It is theoretically impossible to happen.

Comment: @Crush Sundae yes e.g if they both click insert in same time

Comment: Even though they both clicked at the same time, SQL Server will handle it internally. No exceptions or timeouts will happen. All clear?

Comment: everything clear. Last one to not open new topic: Do i need for every single query to implement transaction BeginTransaction + commit/rollback or one query already contains embdeed transaction feature implemented behind and only to put this when there are multi queries as one?

Comment: As per my experience, for example I'm adding from a large datatable (in .NET) to a table (in SQL Server), every loop (every row of data), I have a _BeginTransaction_ and _CommitTransaction_. And in case (although I handled every error, scenario) there are errors, I use a _RollBackTrans_. Basically, that's how the majority uses it (I guess).

Comment: yes but i heard when you got simple query (just one) it's not required to add this because it will be already in transaction but if i would use couple queries as one then i would have to add it. I am not sure about this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118984/discussion-between-crush-sundae-and-jimmyjimm).